# Proper way to draw images in GLJpanel

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

I m using the `GLJpanel` component in my Java swing application, I want to draw images that are Frames from `FFmpegFrameGrabber` in my GLJPanel, to do so my idea was to use the component graphics as mentioned below.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;

public void showImage(GLJPanel panel, Frame frame) {
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
    Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    BufferedImage bfimage = converter.convert(frame);
    graphics.drawImage(bfimage, null, 0,0);
}
```

Is this the proper way to draw images in GL enabled Components or there is another way, I have doubt that I m wrong but I can't prove it

My `GLJPanel` was created as below

```
final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        GLJPanel panel = new GLJPanel(capabilities);
```

Comment: Why not using com.jogamp.opengl.util.av instead? JOGL already uses FFMPEG under the hood.

Comment: could you explain I m not getting what you mean, couldyou provide a minimal example? @gouessej

Comment: JOGL uses FFMPEG for video playback: https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/media/jogl-applet-moviecube01.png Look for the class MovieCube in the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do is to create a `GLEventListener`, this interface have 4 methods `display`, `displayChanged`, `init` and `dispose` then the common parameter `GLAutoDrawable` which is responsible for drawing

in case of drawing images `BufferedImage` I believe that the first step is to convert any image input to `BufferedImage` in my case I enclosed this behaviour in a utility class and fed a queue with my converted images.

to draw you have to use a `Texture` this one can be created using a `TextureData` which will use the buffered image as follow

```
TextureData textureData = AWTTextureIO.newTextureData(gl.getGLProfile(), baseImage, false);
Texture texture = TextureIO.newTexture(textureData);
```

So finally my display should be like

```
public synchronized void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    BufferedImage baseImage = frames.poll();        
    if(baseImage == null)return;

    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


     // Create a TextureData and Texture from it
    TextureData textureData = AWTTextureIO.newTextureData(gl.getGLProfile(), baseImage, false);
    Texture texture = TextureIO.newTexture(textureData);
    // Now draw one quad with the texture
    texture.enable(gl);
    texture.bind(gl);
    gl.glTexEnvi(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL2.GL_REPLACE);
    TextureCoords coords = texture.getImageTexCoords();
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.bottom());
    gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.bottom());
    gl.glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.top());
    gl.glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.top());
    gl.glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
    texture.disable(gl);


    texture.destroy(gl);
    //baseImage = null;
}
```

Comment: Good try but it would be much more efficient if you used a single texture instead of creating a new one at each call of GLEventListener.display() and a single direct NIO buffer to store the data and transfer them into the texture.

Comment: @gouessej thanks for the remarks :) Will be updated